# Install a new color profile on Mac OS 10.8

Tags: display, screen, driver, color

I have a IIYama screen that curerntly display garbages (very, very poor quality).

On the [IIYama](http://www.iiyama.com/gb_en/support/downloads/) website, I found drivers for my screen (ProLite B2409HDS), it contains the following files:

- 2409hds.cat
- 2409HDS.icm
- 2409HDS.inf

And some other files for Windows 7.

But my issue is, on my Display preferences, I can't see any button to add a new profile using my `icm` file :

[image]

If I click on <kbd>Open profile</kbd>, I get a `ColorSync` profile that looks like when I open the given `2409HDS.icm` file manually, so I think there is a way to add it... But can't find it!

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Care to elaborate on what problem you're having with the display? Take a photo of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found how to add profile: put the `icm` file on that directory:

```
Macintosh HD\Library\ColorSync\Profiles
```

And you'll see your profile here....

Anyway, this did not solved my issue, it looks like Apple really want us to buy their incredibly expensive screens. I surely regrets paying 30 boxes to upgrade to 10.8.

Comment: Well, I have an ASUS and it displays correctly...

Comment: I think `.icm` files are in a proprietary Windows-specific format, and won't work with OS X.

Comment: @SilverWolf, it worked for me. But incorrectly ) colors were absolutely wrong and orange. Usually I make the profile derived from the default sRGB one (at the very bottom of default profiles) but it's sill hard to calibrate by looking at dithered fillings on Retina.